# woocommerce_rest_cannot_view with oauth 1.0

Tags: android-studio, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api, oauth-1.0a

I using OAuth 1.0a to authentication my android app as admin to view Woocommercerest API source
I using the retrofit library and it works but today I have this problem

I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources.","data":{"status":401}}
<-- END HTTP (107-byte body)

I tried it with localhost and my real site and the still the same problem
I tried with HTTP and HTTPS and I added useClearTextTrafix to the true and still the same problem
I tried using Woocommerce rest API authentication via HTTP and HTTPS
and still the same problem

my apiClient

```
if (retrofit == null) {

            OAuthInterceptor oauth1WooCommerce = new OAuthInterceptor.Builder()
                    .consumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
                    .consumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
                    .token(TOKEN)
                    .tokenSecret(TOKEN_SECRET)
                    .isShouldExcludeOAuthToken(false)
                    .build();

            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES).readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            builder.addInterceptor(interceptor);

            if (isShouldAddOauth1) {
                builder.addInterceptor(oauth1WooCommerce);
            }

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .client(builder.build())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
```

I saw all the questions in StackOverflow and I didn't find my answer
it works with postman but sometimes I get this error

```
{
    "code": "json_oauth1_signature_mismatch",
    "message": "OAuth signature does not match",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

please help, thank you

Answer (score 1):

not sure but I think the problem from
https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1
because after I deleted it
the problem resolved

And apparently when I tried to authenticate the app using
HTTP Woocommerce Rest API
There is a conflict between the OAuth1 plugin
and Woocommerce Rest API

But My Problem Not Resolved
There Is Another OAuth Plugin WordPress to authenticate the app and make it can view all WordPress rest API source ?

thank you